# Chromecast reciever with WebRtc PeerConnection crashes after 30sec

Tags: webrtc, chromecast, google-cast, custom-receiver

I wrote a screen mirror client app in javascript with html ui, and ran it in chrome browser.
I took same app and deployed as chromecast receiver app, it streams & plays audio/video on chromecast for few seconds and then crashes. I don't see any log information in remote debugger connected.
I am unsure if using webrtc peer connection on chromecast reciever app is supported officially (it clearly works)? If yes, why my app crashes after fixed amount of time?

Also i notice latency starts increasing over time. Not sure why.

Comment: Did you use the Chrome Remote Debugger to see if there are any errors on the receiver?

Comment: No errors messages were thrown. Debugger disconnects as soon as receiver app dies.